# how can i make a program written in c++ with qt to text and graphic mode?

Tags: c++, qt

I have seen in many programs, almost only on linux, that when you run the program with a graphical manager(Clicking the executable) the program runs in a graphical window and when you run it from the terminal it runs on text mode.
I want to know how  to do that. 
Does anyone know how?

Comment: Is your terminal started within a GUI (e.g some `gnome-terminal`) ?

Comment: Usually they're different executables, the GUI one wrapping either the command line app or a shared library that does the work.

Comment: BTW, the canonical way on Linux to start a program is thru the command line. A lot of Linux programs (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ...) don't have desktop icons or menu entries, and your system could have several GUI programs which have no visual counterpart on your desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is operating system specific.

On Linux with [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System), you could simply use the fact that `DISPLAY` is an unset environment variable outside of graphical desktop interfaces (or test for the success of [`XOpenDisplay`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/all/3/xopendisplay/));

You might also use [isatty(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) on `STDIN_FILENO`(which is 0) to test if *stdin* is a terminal (but you could also open `/dev/tty` and see if it fails, cf [tty(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html))
so simply code

```
if (getenv("DISPLAY"))
   startmyGUIapplication();
else if (isatty(STDIN_FILENO)) 
   startmyterminalapplication();
else 
   error(); // application started outside, e.g. from `crontab`
```

Regarding Qt, I guess that [QApplication](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html) would fail to be constructed if not used in a GUI, Or its [exec](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#exec) function would fail.

PS. On Linux with a [Wayland](http://wayland.freedesktop.org/) desktop (or on MacOSX with [Quartz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_%28graphics_layer%29)), I don't know how to do that, but I am sure there is a simple solution.